# Using Dropzone.js in a file_field within a Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js

I am trying to use Dropzone.js to upload files within my Rails app.
It seems that if I use the standard setup, the entire form becomes an image upload field. However, my form contains other fields as well. I only want to use Dropzone.js in a file_field area.

Steps I've used are:

**Gemfile**

`gem 'rails-assets-dropzonejs', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'`

**application.js**

`//= require dropzonejs`

**application.css**

`*= require dropzonejs`

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @activity, html: {class: 'ui form'} do |f| %>
  <!-- Fields like this one don't need to be dropzone fields -->
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <!-- The following field does -->
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :gallery_images %>
    <%= f.file_field :gallery_images, multiple: true, class: 'drop' %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :gallery_images_cache %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**activities.coffee**

```
$ ->
  $('.drop').dropzone({ url: "/activities/post" });
```

As you can see, I'm trying to bind Dropzone to the 'drop' class which I've attached to the file_field. However, this doesn't seem to work correctly and I am seeing no errors in the console.

Anyone have an idea how I'd get Dropzone.js to work for a file_field within a Rails form? Or can I only bind it to the entire form?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Put the field inside a div and give it's id to the dropzone. Worked for me

Comment: Wrapping it within a div seems to have gotten me half way there. Now I'm getting problems with routes. My activities.coffee file now looks like this: `$(".drop").dropzone({url: "/activities/my-activity", headers: {"X-CSRF-Token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')} })` but this is returning an error: `Routing Error No route matches [POST] "/activities/my-activity"`. I wonder how I can change this so that if knows where to post correctly.

Comment: There is such a route, right? Post the routes.rb

Comment: I have `resources :activities` which creates `POST  /activities(.:format)  activities#create`. Should be correct?

Comment: Then the route is POST `/activities` not `/activities/my-activity`

Comment: If I do that, when I try to drag an image onto the Dropzone I see this error instead: `ActionController::ParameterMissing in ActivitiesController#create param is missing or the value is empty: activity`. Whether I add `:activity` to the permitted params or not, I am seeing the same message :(

Comment: Post the relevant controller.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/DaniG2k/5dc1f39c9504a1f361b9235e6573f8a5

Answer (score 0):

You need to permit the `:file` param. Most probably there will be code something along the line of

```
private 

  def activities_params
      params.permit(:name, ...other_params)
  end
```

Add `:file` to the permit method

private

```
  def activities_params
      params.permit(...other_params, :file)
  end
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be correct :( getting the same error: `ActionController::ParameterMissing in ActivitiesController#create param is missing or the value is empty: activity`

Comment: What is this `:activity` param for? You've marked it as required

Comment: Because this is a `form_for @activity`

Comment: I think the problem is that Dropzone doesn't look at the parent form since I'm binding it to a file_field....doesn't seem very versatile

Comment: you don't need to add `:activity` inside permit method. Remove that and add `:file`. I'll check this after I'm back

Comment: I've removed `:activity` and added `:file` instead. No difference :( still seeing `ActionController::ParameterMissing in ActivitiesController#create param is missing or the value is empty: activity`

Comment: Try removing the require. Seems that you are not passing `:activity` as param